# How trustable is eclipse's raw type quick-fix feature?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I'm working on a huge proyect which has over 12k warnings due to unparameterized generic types, since it was started back in the java 1.4 days.
There's no resources (people/time) to manualy fix all these errores, but I'm trying to fix as many as I can whenever I come across one (whenever I have to edit a file with warnings, o call one of those methods).

I've recently noticed that eclipse has a quick-fix feature for this type of warning as well, and I tried it on several files, carefully checking that fix is correct (ie: if an `ArrayList` is parameterized as `<String>`, I check that everything that is added/getted is a String).

I've been running this on several files, and carefully following these parameterized variables to make sure the fix is ok, and eclipse seems never to miss.

My question is, how trustable *is* this feature? Am I safe running in on all 12k warning without manually checking every one, or is there a risk of some erroneous fix by doing this? Will eclipse skip parameters it can't guess, or will it still do a best-effort?

Comment: It might sound stupid but: how about trying, see if it compiles / passes your tests. If not, revert to previous version in your Version Control System?

Comment: If any errors occur, they're probably compile-time errors that Eclipse will show you automatically.  See how many of those occur?

Comment: There are no compile-time errores, and it builds fine.  I'm worried about run-time errors.  Since the system is huge, it would probably take QA weeks to re-test the entire thing, we can only re-test critical parts, but I don't want the blame for this blowing up in production.

Comment: @LukasEder: Not really, maybe someone has experience using this in mass scale, or actually know the inner workings of this feature better than me.

Comment: @Hugo: On a second thought, you're probably right...

Comment: @Hugo generics are AFAIR usually only checked at compile-time. Only if you explicitly check them by your code at run-time they are used at that time.

Comment: Excelent point, I had forgotten about this.  They make no difference at runtime, so if it builds, it works!  This should be an answer, no comment! :)

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: It is reliable.

You can also read about what JDT/UI team did to generify their code - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Generify_A_Java_Project#Generify_your_project

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to disable that warning for the project(s). In Project Properties, navigate to Java Compiler > Errors/Warning, then type "raw" (without the quotes) in the search box. You can change the "Usage of raw type" from a warning to Ignore.

Another option is to add the @SuppressWarnings annotation (also a QuickFix option).

Personally, I find that warning annoying, as there are many cases when generics aren't needed or don't provide value.

Comment: Ideally, in large proyects, it's better to actually clean up these warnings.  It helps have a clearer interface as to what methods return, or whan a list (por example) contains.  I find that disabling warnings generally degrades code quality, either for legibility, maintainability, or robustness.